# Solving the system $a^2-6=2\sqrt{2c+6}, \, b^2-6=2\sqrt{2a+6}, \, c^2-6=2\sqrt{2b+6}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

**Question:**

> Solve the following system for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> b^2-6=2\sqrt{2a+6}\\
> c^2-6=2\sqrt{2b+6}\\
> a^2-6=2\sqrt{2c+6}
> \end{cases}$$

I found the following:$$ (b^2-6)^2=4(2a+6)$$
$$(c^2-6)^2=4(2b+6)$$
$$(a^2-6)^2=4(2c+6)$$
Then maybe $a=b=c$ is one case.

Thank you.

Comment: the symmetry might sugest that indeed $a=b=c$.

Comment: What kind of number are $a$, $b$ and $c$? Integer? Real? Complex?

Comment: For the $a=b=c$ case, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-6%3D2sqrt%282x%2B6%29) finds $-1-\sqrt 3, 1+\sqrt 7$  When I gave it the whole system it timed out.

Comment: As the OP requested, this **does** have solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ where $a\neq b\neq c$. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, this system ***does*** have solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ where $a\neq b\neq c$. Unfortunately, it involves a deg-$54$ equation. Given,

$$ (b^2-6)^2=4(2a+6)\tag1$$
$$(c^2-6)^2=4(2b+6)\tag2$$
$$(a^2-6)^2=4(2c+6)\tag3$$

Do the substitutions:

$$a =\tfrac{1}{2}(-6+x^2)\tag4$$

$$b =\tfrac{1}{8}(12-12c^2+c^4)\tag5$$

$$c =\tfrac{1}{128}(-240  - 288x^2 + 168 x^4 - 24 x^6 + x^8)\tag6$$

This satisfies $(2),(3)$. However, $(1)$ is satisfied if a factorable $2+2+6+54=64$-deg eqn in $x$ is solved. The quadratic roots are $-1\pm\sqrt{3},\,1\pm\sqrt{7}$ which yield $a=b=c$, the sextic has all complex roots, but the $54$-deg has ***12 real roots***. (You can see that monster equation in all its glory here: [*WolframAlpha resultant*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B-240-288c%5E2%2B168c%5E4-24c%5E6%2Bc%5E8-128x%2C%20-240-128c-288x%5E2%2B168x%5E4-24x%5E6%2Bx%5E8%2Cc%5D%5D).)

From the definitions of $(4),(5),(6)$, if $x$ is real, then $a,b,c$ are also real and $a\neq b\neq c$. We give one root to 50 decimal places,

$$x =-2.9849962763167580809615620439502727527653816890554$$

so,

$$\begin{align}
a &= 1.4551013848124557801133370412617382434937978383740\dots\\
b &= -0.1732265781180354496841227929738397618222596966\dots\\
c &= -1.1155995411074882152529545257291565862139304073\dots\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ 3T:=a^2+b^2+c^2-18 = 2\sqrt{2a+6} +
   2\sqrt{2b+6} + 2\sqrt{2c+6} $$

If $$ a= {\rm max}\ \{ a,b,c\},\ b
 = {\rm min}\ \{ a,b,c\},\ a>b$$ then
 $$T>b^2-6=2\sqrt{2a+6} > T$$

Contradiction.

Comment: Contradiction? The system has solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ where $a\neq b\neq c$.

Comment: I see. There exists an error in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$(b^2-6)^2-(c^2-6)^2=8(a-b)\Leftrightarrow (b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2-12)=8(a-b)$$
$$(b^2-6)^2-(a^2-6)^2=8(a-c)\Leftrightarrow (b^2-a^2)(b^2+a^2-12)=8(a-c)$$
$$(c^2-6)^2-(a^2-6)^2=8(b-c)\Leftrightarrow (c^2-a^2)(c^2+a^2-12)=8(b-c)$$
Assume that $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$ then 
$$b^2+c^2\geq 12$$
on the other hand
$$b^2+a^2\leq12$$
and $$c^2+a^2\leq12$$
which would yield $$b^2+a^2\leq b^2+c^2\Leftrightarrow a^2\leq c^2\Leftrightarrow a\leq c$$ and 
$$c^2+a^2\leq c^2+b^2\Leftrightarrow a^2\leq b^2\Leftrightarrow a\leq b$$
Therefore $a=b=c$.
It remains to check when not all of them are positive.