# A clue to solve the system of equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases} x +y=\sqrt[2107]{z}\\y +z=\sqrt[2107]{x}\\z +x=\sqrt[2107]{y}\end{cases}$$ 
It is obvious that $(0,0,0)$ is an answer , but How can be sure for other solution (If other solution exists ) ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a contest problem from 2107 ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus : I don't know ,but I think so

Comment: @Khosrotash: I would like to know who is going to win the NBA playoffs in $2107$, in such a case.

Comment: @Khosrotash Forward To The Future!

Comment: $(x+y)^{2107}=z,\;(z+y)^{2107}=x,\;(x+z)^{2107}=y$
$$(x+(x+z)^{2107})^{2107}=z$$
another solution must be very very tiny

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  You want to make the BET of your life in $2107$, don't you?

Comment: @Raffaele: just planning to make it, I still need to get a cryogenic device to be there in one piece.

Comment: Why do most OPs "forget" to explain the crucial thing: why would anybody care? It's trivial to throw together a few symbols so that it's a difficult looking problem, and thus sort of "cool"  for some simple minds, but... in all the hints concerning the criteria for up- or downvotes, the word "useful" is significant. It's also obvious that $x=y=z=(1/2)^{2107/2106}$ is a solution, so what? Who needs those solutions? Who needs a method absolutely useless for the next equation?

Comment: There is a solution such that $x=y=z$.

Comment: There are solutions $x=y\neq z$ but $x,y,z$ are complex numbers. By the FTA, these are also valid solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} x +y=\sqrt[2107]{z}\\y +z=\sqrt[2107]{x}\\z +x=\sqrt[2107]{y}\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} x -y=\sqrt[2107]{y}-\sqrt[2107]{x}\\y -z=\sqrt[2107]{z}-\sqrt[2107]{y}\\z -x=\sqrt[2107]{x}-\sqrt[2107]{z}\end{cases}$$

This implies $$\sqrt[2107]{x}+x=\sqrt[2107]{y}+y=\sqrt[2107]{z}+z$$ which is satisfied by $x=y=z$ This common value is given by the first (or second or third) equation $$2x=\sqrt[2107]{x}\Rightarrow x^{1-\frac{1}{2017}}=x^{\frac{2016}{2017}}=\dfrac 12\Rightarrow x=\sqrt[2016]{\frac{1}{2^{2017}}}$$

**Uniqueness**.-Suppose that x is real (*see the answer of Tito Piezas III*) and that $x\lt y$ so $y=x+h$ where $h\gt 0$.

The derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt[2107]{x}$ is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2017\sqrt[2107]{x^{2016}}}\gt 0$ then $f$ is increasing.

$$\sqrt[2107]{x}+x=\sqrt[2107]{y}+y\Rightarrow\sqrt[2107]{x}=\sqrt[2107]{x+h}+h\Rightarrow h=0\text{ because f is increasing  }$$

Contradiction with $h\gt 0$.

Comment: Explaining for clarity, $x-y=y^k-x^k$ comes from $x-z=z^k-x^k$ and $y-z=z^k-y^k$

Comment: The crucial point is to explain why **every** real solution fulfills $x=y=z$.

Comment: I agree. I will try to do it in a different way to you (I had seen that the graph of the curve is a line (the diagonal) which also indicated that $ x = y $ but I omitted mentioning it. I always appreciate your answers. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

There are very few real solutions.

By enforcing the substitution $x=a^{2107},y=b^{2107},z=c^{2107}$ the problem boils down to solving
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}c-b^{2107}&=&a^{2107}\\ b^{2107}+c^{2107}&=&a\\b-c^{2107}&=&a^{2107}\end{array}\right.$$
and by assuming $b\neq c$, the first and the third equation imply
$$ \frac{b^{2107}-c^{2107}}{b-c}=b^{2106}+b^{2105}c+\ldots+b c^{2105}+c^{2106} = -1 $$
which is impossible since the LHS is clearly positive. By symmetry it follows that the only solutions are given by $x=y=z=0,\,$ or $x=y=z=\pm 2^{-2107/2106}$.

Comment: Fixed a small typo. He comes from the year 2106, after all.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: many thanks from the future.

Comment: By the way, the OP should have specified he wanted solutions in the ***reals***. Because there are in fact extra solutions $x=y\neq z$ but $x,y,z$ are complex.

Answer (score 1):

The OP didn't specify ***real*** solutions. Given the system,
$$\begin{cases} 
(x+y)^n = z\\
(y+z)^n = x\\
(x+z)^n = y\end{cases}$$

Assume $x = y$. Hence,
$$\begin{cases} 
(2x)^n = z\\
(x+z)^n = x\\
(x+z)^n = x\end{cases}$$

So we just have,

$$\big(x+(2x)^n\big)^n = x$$

By the *Fundamental Theorem of Algebra* (FTA), this has $n^2$ complex solutions. (And as the other answers showed, $2$ of these are real.)

---

**P.S.** For an example of a system that surprisingly turned out to have extra ***real*** solutions (from a $54$-deg poly), see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975207/solving-the-system-a2-6-2-sqrt2c6-b2-6-2-sqrt2a6-c2-6-2-sqrt2).